# Wrong port connection between my vps and git through ssh

Tags: git, server, vps

I'm here to ask about a problem that i've been getting in the last hours with me new vps.

After the vps installation i've received a mail with the access to my vps, into this email i got ssh access credentials.

I did the following steps to connect my vps with git:

- 1- Create ssh key
- 2- Authorize it
- 3- Add this key on gitlab
- 4- Create    new repository on gitlab
- 5- Git clone    git@gitlab.com:mygituser/projectname.git

And then i got this error:

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection refused fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I've already added the ssh key of the vps to gitlab!

The most important reason and the most considerable is that the ssh port by default of my server is 13411 and ssh default port (On git in this case) is 22.

What i can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the error message you obtain when you `git clone git@gitlab.com:mygituser/projectname.git`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I've already added the ssh key of the vps to gitlab!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you edit your question and add the error message to it?

Comment: Ready... thanks! Do you have some tip to tell me ?